# How to change the output directory in Snakemake without using cd

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to get GiRaF (https://github.com/sdwfrost/giraf) running on Kubernetes using Azure Blob Storage - it's not my code, I've just fixed a few errors, wrote a Dockerfile, and a test Snakefile. I want to do repeat runs, so my solution for the local filesystem is here:

```
# Set number of repeats
N = 2

def repeat_runs():
    files=[]
    for i in range(0,N,1):
        files.append("run_"+str(i+1)+"/left-right_report")
    return files

rule all:
    input:
        repeat_runs()

rule giraf:
    input:
        "{r}/in.giraf"
    output:
        "{r}/left-right_report"
    params:
        infile="in.giraf"
    shell:
        "cd {wildcards.r};giraf {params.infile}"

rule copy_infile:
    input:
        "in.giraf"
    output:
        "{r}/in.giraf"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

However, I can't change directory like this using Azure Blob Storage - I can create and copy files however. Has anyone encountered something like this before? Giraf is actually multiple subprograms so it would be more time consuming to add in an argument for the output directory.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure Blob Storage - what do you mean by *I can't change directory like this*?

Comment: Blob Storage isn't mounted as a file system (though there are ways to set this up, but that's another layer of complexity).